# Какой Eclipse использовать для программирования на Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Какой Eclipse использовать для программирования на Java?

- Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers
- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Какая между ними разница? Какой из них использовать для написания Java приложений на тел и комп (не онлайн)?

Comment: Отредактировал исключительно из перфекционизма. Переоткрывать не надо.

Answer (score 2):

Java EE (Enterprise Edition) - это программирование серьезных программ и сервисов для предприятий с ориентировкой на веб-технологии. Если твоя цель писать программы под desktop или mobile, то тебе вполне подойдет Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. Если ты новичок, то я тебе рекомендую вместо Eclipse скачать IntelliJ IDEA, так как она проще и удобнее в освоении для неопытных, а платную версию нужно покупать только, если твоя цель Java EE (могу тут ошибаться, если что - поправьте меня). Для мобильных устройств используется Java ME (Micro Edition), но эта технология уже вымирает из-за Android. Если же тебя все таки интересует разработка под Android, то вместо Eclipse сейчас все разработчики переходят на Android Studio от Google, который создан на основе IntelliJ IDEA, поэтому тоже рекомендую уже начинать с него.

Comment: *могу тут ошибаться, если что - поправьте меня*. Поправляю.

Comment: Idea умнее чем Еклипс

Answer (score 1):

используй Intellij Idea!

А разница вот в чем Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers
This package includes:

- Data Tools Platform
- Eclipse Git Team Provider
- Eclipse Java Development Tools
- Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
- JavaScript Development Tools
- Maven Integration for Eclipse
- Mylyn Task List
- Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment
- Remote System Explorer
- Code Recommenders Tools for Java Developers
- Eclipse XML Editors and Tools

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

- Eclipse Git Team Provider
- Eclipse Java Development Tools
- Maven Integration for Eclipse
- Mylyn Task List
- Code Recommenders Tools for Java Developers
- WindowBuilder Core
- Eclipse XML Editors and Tools

и вообще для новичка IDE это зло TextPad или командная строка для начало а потом только IDE

Answer (score 0):

Ee для веб-разработки заточен. Второй для софтверных разработчиков. Разница в плюшках для категорий разработчиков